# JSON: How do I select an array inside another array?

Tags: arrays, json

I have the current JSON file:

```
[{"id":"1","images":[{"img_id":"1"},{"img_id":"2"},{"img_id":"3"}]},
[{"id":"2","images":[{"img_id":"1"},{"img_id":"2"},{"img_id":"3"}]}
```

How do I select the array with ID 1 and list every 'img_id' inside it, without repeating it for the other array?

**edit 1:**
I am trying to parse it like this but this code is erroneous:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
$.getJSON("../path/to/json", function(data) {
$.each(data[0].images.img_id, function(i,data){
var new_data ="<p src='path/to/folder/"+images.img_id+"'></p>";             
$(new_data).appendTo("#htmlTag");
});
}); return false;
});
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: This isn't even valid JSON... can you please double check it?

Comment: what you have here is an array with json that arrays with json in them its all messy in your should reformat it

Comment: @Polaris878 yeah the formatting is probably a mess i just typed it off the top of my head, but this is what it actually look like: demo.gallerycms.com/index.php/view/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects, where each object contains another array of objects.  I'm assuming the JSON structure you are using is:

```
var a = [{"id":"1","images":[{"img_id":"1"},{"img_id":"2"},{"img_id":"3"}]},
         {"id":"2","images":[{"img_id":"1"},{"img_id":"2"},{"img_id":"3"}]}];
```

I'm also assuming you are using JavaScript.

---

**PostEdit:**

Your code is fairly close, I believe what I have below should work:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("../path/to/json", function(data) {
        $.each(data[0].images, function(i,data){
            var new_data ="<p src='path/to/folder/" + data.img_id + "'></p>";             
            $(new_data).appendTo("#htmlTag");
        });
    }); 

    return false;
});
```

All I did was change the first parameter to your `each` call from: `data[0].images.img_id` to: `data[0].images`.  Also, I changed the declaration of `new_data` from:

```
var new_data ="<p src='path/to/folder/"+images.img_id+"'></p>";
```

to:

```
var new_data ="<p src='path/to/folder/"+data.img_id+"'></p>";
```

Note that the parameter "data" in the each callback function is simply the element in the array, while "i" is the index of that element in the array.  Therefore, data is an object which looks like this:

```
{"img_id":1}
```

So, you can get the ID via `data.img_id`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited my post, I added a code which I had which doesn't work, how would you modify it with your code? or maybe correct it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about references. I don't think they are possible in JSON. In case you strictly need them and still want the readable serialization of your objects - I'd suggest you to look into [YAML](http://yaml.org)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in your JSON...it seems like a bracket is missing at the end, and one has been added at the start of line 2. But, assuming you meant this (and are using Javascript):

```
var myJson = [{"id":"1","images":[{"img_id":"1"},{"img_id":"2"},{"img_id":"3"}]},
             {"id":"2","images":[{"img_id":"1"},{"img_id":"2"},{"img_id":"3"}]}];
```

then you can access whatever you need just like a nested Javascript object. If you wanted to only access the object with ID equal to 1, *and order is not guaranteed*, you would have to iterate:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++){
    if(myJson[i].id === "1"){
        var imgs = myJson[i].images;
        for(var j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++){
            //do what you want with imgs[j].img_id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yes it's in javascript ... I've edited my post to include the code which I have, can you see why it doesn't work? Much appreciated.